C++ wxWidgets: How do I refer to an element of my frame?
Let's say I have a button on my Frame inside a panel, and I have a static text inside a panel on the same level of the panel where the button is. How can I modify let's say the background colour or the text of the static text when I press the button?
So, I have the function that run on the event left up liked to the button but I don't know how to refer to the static text inside my event function. I have the frame as an argument of my class derived from wxFrame. I saw there's a method GetChildred() but I don't have any idea how to go after that to get the right element I need
main.cpp
// ----------------- INCLUDE
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "gui.h"

//------------------ MYAPP CLASS
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override;
};
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    GuiFrame *frame = new GuiFrame();
    frame->ShowFrame();
    return true;
}

//------------------ ENTRY POINT MACRO
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

gui.h:
#ifndef GUI_H_INCLUDED
// ----------------- INCLUDE
#define GUI_H_INCLUDED

// ----------------- GUI FRAME CLASS
class GuiFrame : public wxFrame
{
private:
    // Attributes
    wxFrame *frame;

public:
    //Constructor
    GuiFrame();

    // Event function
    void OnToolBtn(wxMouseEvent& event);

    // Methods
    void ShowFrame();

};
#endif

gui.cpp:
// ----------------- INCLUDE
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include "gui.h"

// ------------------------------- CLASS GuiFrame

//------ Constructor
GuiFrame::GuiFrame()
{
    frame = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Mapping Manager", wxPoint(100,100),wxSize(600,600));
    wxPanel *pnl_one= new wxPanel(frame, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,30));
    pnl_one->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(245,208,51)); //Yellow
    pnl_one-> Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, OnToolBtn, this);

    wxPanel *pnl_two= new wxPanel(frame, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,30));
    pnl_two->SetBackgroundColour(wxColor(3,173,252)); //Blue

    wxBoxSizer *mainSizer= new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    mainSizer-> Add(pnl_one, 0, wxEXPAND);
    mainSizer-> Add(pnl_two, 1, wxEXPAND);

    frame->SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer);
}
//------ Methods
void GuiFrame::OnToolBtn(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    wxLogMessage(wxString::Format(wxT("%i"),event.GetId()));
}

void GuiFrame::ShowFrame()
{
    frame->Show(true);
}

Above there's my code. What I'm trying to do here is to change colour of the blue panel when i click the yellow one
thanks

Post code along with the description of the code. We need a [mcve].

@LucaVieceli, you handle wrong event and need to look at the widgets sample provided to you. Also you should check you C++ knowledge.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to handle the EVT_BUTTON Event, and make the static text a member of that frame. You should learn something about wxWidgets first.

@LucaVieceli,
Lets fix your code...

The member of the GuiFrame - "wxFrame *frame"

What is the purpose of having a pointer to itself? Get rid of it...

Make pnl_one and pnl_two members of the GuiFrame instead.

Bind the wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN event to the panel which will handle the click.

In the handler change the color of the other panel. DON'T FORGET TO CALL event.Skip()!!!

Compile and run.


You need to go learn C++, then start coding. The first issue gives you away as a very new to the language itself very clearly.
We will expect more questions from you in regards to the language itself and not necessary wxWidgets if you don't do that.
On top of everything I said - are you sure you need both of those as panels and not just buttons?
Think you design thru...
HTH.

Thanks for the answer but I don't understand the first point. If I don't use the pointer but I just use "wxFrame frame" when I create the frame with the new operator compiler gives me an error and I thought it needed a pointer. What should I do if I want the wxFrame as a class argument?

@LucaVieceli, what error? Like I said - you need a knowledge on the language itself...

@LucaVieceli, get rid of that member variable. You are creating the frme in the application constructor... And please do go and learn C++ - its not a trivial language...
